# How to get POI of a city and its latitude and longitude in a country in DBPedia?

Tags: geolocation, dbpedia, point-of-interest

I am trying to get POI (hotels, restaurants, etc) from DBPedia.
The query is limited to a city of a country, for example Seoul in South Korea.
The query should return the longitude and latitude of the POI.
Here is the example of my code:

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
SELECT * 
  WHERE {
 ?inst ?nameprop ?label .
 FILTER (?nameprop=foaf:name || ?nameprop=rdfs:label) .
 FILTER (lang(?label) = "en") .
 ?inst a ?cls .
 FILTER (?cls = <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/Hotel>
)
}limit 100
```

How should I modify that query to get the latitude and longitude of a POI and also to add the city and country as the filters?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The following query may help you. You can change the country name as you wish.

```
PREFIX ont: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX geo: <http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#>

select *
{
   ?poi rdf:type ont:City . 
   ?poi ?locatedIn :Iran .
   ?poi rdfs:label ?name FILTER (lang(?name) = "en") .
   ?poi geo:lat ?lat .
   ?poi geo:long ?long .
} limit 100
```